# Plot highly correlated words against a specific word of interest

Tags: r, graphviz, tm

I am trying to plot the highest correlation of a word.  For example, I want to graph the highest ten correlations of the word "whale."  Can someone help me with the command for something like that?  I have RGraphViz installed if that helps.

```
s.dir1<-"/PATHTOTEXT/MobyDickTxt"

s.cor1<-Corpus(DirSource(s.dir1), readerControl=list(reader=readPlain))
s.cor1<-tm_map(s.cor1, removePunctuation)
s.cor1<-tm_map(s.cor1, stripWhitespace)
s.cor1<-tm_map(s.cor1, tolower)
s.cor1<-tm_map(s.cor1, removeNumbers)
s.cor1<-tm_map(s.cor1, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
tdm1 <- TermDocumentMatrix(s.cor1)

m1 <- as.matrix(tdm)
v1 <- sort(rowSums(m), decreasing=TRUE)
d1 <- data.frame(word = names(v),freq=v)
```

Comment: What kind of graph?  You really have to be more explicit than this.

Comment: I don't really have a preference.  I am presenting some research that involves looking at the correlation between emotional words in historical documentation.  As a result, anything that would allow an audience member to view the relationship well is fine with me.

Comment: I'd recommend a dotplot then.  Please use google fu with R and dotplot and try to figure it out on your own.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a method to compute the top words correlating with a given word in a corpus, and plot those words and correlations.

Get example data...

```
require(tm)
data("crude")
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(crude)
```

Compute correlations and store in data frame...

```
toi <- "oil" # term of interest
corlimit <- 0.7 #  lower correlation bound limit.
oil_0.7 <- data.frame(corr = findAssocs(tdm, toi, corlimit)[[1]],
                  terms = names(findAssocs(tdm, toi, corlimit)[[1]]))
```

Create a factor to allow ggplot to sort the dataframe...

```
oil_0.7$terms <- factor(oil_0.7$terms ,levels = oil_0.7$terms)
```

Draw the plot...

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(oil_0.7, aes( y = terms  ) ) +
  geom_point(aes(x = corr), data = oil_0.7) +
  xlab(paste0("Correlation with the term ", "\"", toi, "\""))
```

[image]

Comment: this response inspired a plotting method for qdap's `word_cor` function.  I gave you credit but as Ben from SO.  If you'd like to have your full name used please send me an email.

Comment: Code snippet doesn't work :(

Comment: its a very trivial glitch: corr and terms have different size; using row.names instead of names works, then i just need to change the name for the first variable to corr and thats'it :)

Comment: @GabrieleB Yes, I see. I've updated the answer and it should work fine now. Looks like there was a change to `tm::findAssocs` since I posted the original answer.

Comment: Tnx allot for the fix! It works like a charm now!

Comment: No worries, thanks for identifying and describing the problem.