# R : Visualize correlated words against one or more words

Tags: r, plot, correlation, tm

I have a corpus of 11 text documents. I have found word associations using the commands:

```
findAssocs(dtm, c("youngster","campaign"), corlimit=0.9) 
findAssocs(dtms, "corruption", corlimit=0.9)
```

dtm is a document term matrix.

```
 dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(docs)
```

where docs is the corpus.

dtms is the document term matrix after removing 10% sparse terms.

```
dtms <- removeSparseTerms(dtm, 0.1)
```

I would like to plot the correlated terms I got against (i) 2 specific words and (ii) 1 specific word
I tried following this post : [Plot highly correlated words against a specific word of interest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19549280/plot-highly-correlated-words-against-a-specific-word-of-interest)

```
toi <- "corruption" # term of interest
corlimit <- 0.9 #  lower correlation bound limit.
cor_0.9 <- data.frame(corr = findAssocs(dtm, toi, corlimit)[,1],terms=row.names(findAssocs(dtm, toi, corlimit)))
```

But unfortunately the code :

```
cor_0.9 <- data.frame(corr = findAssocs(dtm, toi, corlimit)[,1],terms=row.names(findAssocs(dtm, toi, corlimit)))
```

gives me an error :

```
Error in findAssocs(dtm, toi, corlimit)[, 1]:incorrect number of dimensions
```

This is the structure of the document term matrix:

```
dtm
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 11, terms: 1847)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 8024/12293
Sparsity           : 61%
Maximal term length: 23
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
```

and in the environemt it is of form:

```
dtm                 List of 6
i: int [1:8024] 1  1  1  1  1  ...
j: int [1:8024] 17 29 34 43 47 ...
v: num [1:8024] 9  4  9  5  5  ...
nrow : int 11
ncol : int 1847
dimnames: list of 2
...$ Docs : chr [1:11]  "character (0)" "character (0)" "character (0)"
...$ Terms: chr [1:1847] "campaigning"|__truncated__"a"|__"truncated"__ 
attr(*,"class") = chr [1:2] "DocumentTermMatrix" "simple_triplet_matrix"...
attr(*,"weighting") = chr [1:2] "term frequency" "tf"
```

How do I plot word correlations for a single word and multiple words? Please help.

Here is the output of

```
findAssocs(dtm, c("youngster","campaign"), corlimit=0.9)

$youngster
   character         colleges      controversi           expect          corrupt             much 
        1.00             1.00             1.00             1.00             0.99             0.99 
        okay          saritha         existing            leads          satisfi           social 
        0.99             0.99             0.98             0.98             0.98             0.98

$campaign
basic      make      lack  internal   general    method satisfied      time 
 0.95      0.95      0.94      0.93      0.92      0.92      0.92      0.92
```

Comment: I don't have any experience with the functions you describe, but the error is a common one. You get some kind of output from `findAssocs`. You try to subset it with `[,1]`, but the error tells you that those dimensions are wrong. Could you provide the output of `findAssocs(dtms, "corruption", corlimit=0.9)` so I can see what it looks like?

Comment: @Laterow surely. I have added the output in the question

Comment: I wrote [the answer that you linked to](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19925445/1036500), and after reading your question here, I have edited my answer to make it work again. Give it a try again let us know what you get.

Comment: @Ben Thank you,it worked! Is there a way for getting the correlation plot for two words instead of one for the above same situation ? I tried c("word1","word2") instead of "toi" in the line :

    oil_0.7 <- data.frame(corr = findAssocs(tdm, toi, corlimit)[[1]],terms =names(findAssocs(tdm, toi, corlimit)[[1]]))

but it shows the correlation plot for only the first word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly different approach is required for two words, here's a quick attempt:

```
require(tm)
data("crude")
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(crude)

# Compute correlations and store in data frame...

toi1 <- "oil" # term of interest
toi2 <- "winter"
corlimit <- 0.7 #  lower correlation bound limit.

corr1 <-  findAssocs(tdm, toi1, corlimit)[[1]]
corr1 <- cbind(read.table(text = names(corr1), stringsAsFactors = FALSE), corr1)
corr2 <- findAssocs(tdm, toi2, corlimit)[[1]]
corr2 <- cbind(read.table(text = names(corr2), stringsAsFactors = FALSE), corr2)

# join them together
library(dplyr)
two_terms_corrs <- full_join(corr1, corr2)

# gather for plotting
library(tidyr)
two_terms_corrs_gathered <- gather(two_terms_corrs, term, correlation, corr1:corr2)

# insert the actual terms of interest so they show up on the legend
two_terms_corrs_gathered$term <- ifelse(two_terms_corrs_gathered$term  == "corr1", toi1, toi2)


# Draw the plot...

require(ggplot2)
ggplot(two_terms_corrs_gathered, aes(x = V1, y = correlation, colour =  term ) ) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  ylab(paste0("Correlation with the terms ", "\"", toi1,  "\"", " and ",  "\"", toi2, "\"")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]